# Visualizing planes, cross-products and lines ; in this question, how is w x n the direction of PQ?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, euclidean-geometry, cross-product, plane-geometry

I'd like some geometrical insight if possible. Why is PQ in the same direction as the cross product of w and n? PQ lies in the plane, so it should be perpendicular to n. How is it also perpendicular to w? Diagrams will be hugely appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have $$\overrightarrow{AQ}\parallel\underline{n}$$

By definition of cross-product, $$\underline{w}\perp\underline{n}$$ and $$\underline{w}\perp\overrightarrow{AP}$$

Therefore $\underline{w}$ is normal to the plane $APQ$

Thus $\underline{n}\times\underline{w}$ is parallel to plane $\Pi$ and to plane $APQ$ and is therefore parallel to $\overrightarrow{PQ}$ which is the line of intersection of these two planes.

So the equation of the line $PQ$ is $$\underline{r}=\overrightarrow{OP}+\lambda\underline{n}\times\underline{w}$$

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense, although I would have preferred a more visual approach.. It's very difficult to think of it as the intersection of two planes when the problem hasn't mentioned it.

Comment: You are welcome. A diagram would be quite simple, but I don't have a suitable drawing package on my ipad.

Comment: @Saad A good way to develop the sort of visual geometrical insight you want is to try drawing a diagram yourself.

Comment: @amd I've tried that, but I really can't get it unless I think of the line PQ as the intersection of two planes. It could just be that I can't draw a convincing diagram on paper though.

Comment: @Saad Try using [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/) or a similar program. Trying to sketch 3-D relationships can get difficult very quickly.

Comment: @amd Thanks! Will do.

Comment: @amd I've added a picture which illustrates the situation to the best of my ability. I haven't actually drawn w since I don't think I can draw it accurately perpendicularly. I still don't get why w must be perpendicular to PQ. (AC in this case)

Comment: @Saad See https://ggbm.at/psWwa5PT for a more complete diagram.

Comment: @amd I still don't get it.